# Products.SQLAlchemyPAS works as foreground but not as service

Tags: plone

I have SQLAlchemyPAS with little customisation. product works fine with foreground mode but when I run as service it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the error log for your instance?

Comment: You'll need to ask a more specific question. What are you expecting to happen, and what is happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

Its was permission issue. sorted now. cfg file needed username and password for database connection string.